# Why referenced object is still available when parent object is set to null

Tags: javascript

Why a referenced object is not set to null when parent object is set to null in JavaScript?

```
var objA = { 1 : "hello" };
var objB = objA;
objA = null;

console.log(objB);  // { 1 : "hello" }
```

Why `objB` is not set to `null`? How object referencing works here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables never "contain" objects, they simply contain a *reference* to an object.

`var objB = objA;` simply copies the *reference* stored in `objA`, making them point to the same object. When `objA` is set to `null`, it means that it no longer points to anything. However, `objB` still contains a reference to the object.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `objB` **does not** reference `objA`. It references the thing that `objA` is currently referencing. Therefore, modifying `objA` has no effect on `objB`.

Think of it this way:

```
var a = "test"; //a -> "test"
var b = a;      //a -> "test" <- b
a = null; //a -> null, "test" <- b
```

Consider the following image:

[image]

This is what your first two lines do: set `a` and `b` to point to the same object. Now when you change `b` to null:

[image]

`a` is unchanged.

Comment: Why do you think it copies the value?

Comment: @VisioN Sorry, my wording was a bit ambiguous. Edited

Answer (score 0):

It works just as it works on any other value. Try using numbers or strings instead of objects:

```
var objA = 5
var objB = objA
objA = null;
```

The only special thing about objects (as opposed to numbers, etc) is that objects are mutable so if you set a property of an object then all variables that reference that object will see the change.

Perhaps the word reference is confusing you to think it has the same meaning in as it has in C++. In fact, what happens in Javascipt is that variables behave more like pointers (but without the pointer arithmetic and with derefferencing being implicit). So if you have two variables pointing to the same object then if you change properties via oe pointer it will also be visible via the other pointer. On the other hand, if you change the value of the pointer by assigning it to some other pointer then the other pointers that used to point to that place don't get changed.

So, translating your example to C it could look something like

```
Obj *a = malloc_new_obj()
Obj *b = a;

//Both pointers point to the same object
a->some_property = 10
printf("%d\n", b->some_property); //should get 10 too

//but assigning the pointer itself doesn't change the otehr pointers
a = NULL;
printf("%d\n", b->some_property); //should still work
```

var objB = objA;
objA = null;

Comment: @VisioN: I wanted to change the value to a number but forgot to actually do that.

Comment: Exactly! That's why C knowledge is mandatory for every programmer, even if she doesn't write any C code at all.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and unhelpful.  Comparisons to a language that the OP likely doesn't now will just confuse the issue, and comparing primitive value assignment to object references just glosses over what's actually happening and the possibility to share references.  It sounds like he's looking for an explanation that is simple, not technical and analogous.

Comment: @MattWhipple: calm down dude. how are you so sure the OP doesn't know C++, given how its one of the few common language nowadays that actually has references that do what he was thinking of. And honestly I don't see how this is glossing over anything. The assignment semantics really are equivalent to C++ pointers.

Comment: @thg435 Saying C knowledge is mandatory downplays alternate paradigms.  If you work with functional languages, then C will just lead to poor practice.

Comment: @missingno I'm not sure.  Neither of us knows, that's why it's a poor answer, it introduces an entirely external, unmentioned, and unneeded context.  If the OP does happen to know C then the answer will still be less useful for anyone that doesn't.  It glosses over the issue because it doesn't cover when references to mutable objects are shared in JavaScript, opening the door to simple bugs and also possibilities for inadvertent critical section issues with asynchrony.

Comment: @MattWhipple: sheesh guy, I also hate C just like you do. I think you are missing my point. If the guy knows C then the analogy will answer the question imediatly. If he doesn't then someone else will point another answer. The diversity isn't hurting anyone and its not like I am saying things that are wrong or profoundly misleading. And I did, in fact, cover the part of sharing references, although explicitly in the C part. If you wanted that to be clearer then its just a matter of pointing out that Javascript objects can be mutable. (a simple edit or comment)